# Carregar informações do firebase no RecyclerView - Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, algoritmo-de-busca

Meu app armazena informações dos clientes no Firebase e descarrega em um ListView, mas preciso fazer uma pesquisa com as informações no ListView. Me falaram que a melhor forma de fazer é usar um RecyclerView com SearchView. O problema que estou meio perdido, com o listView usei o FirebaseUI que facilitou bastante carregar os dados do Firebase. Mas com o RecyclerView aparentemente tenho que criar uma classe ViewHolder (isso que estou com duvida, tenho que criar realmente?), e não consegui intender direito a documentação do FirebaseUI para o RecyclerView. Alguém tem algum tutorial, ou dica para isso, estou pesquisando bastante, então qualquer informação pode ser útil. Obrigadoooo.

Comment: Consegue carregar um ArrayList<>() com as informações do firebase?

Comment: Pode ser uma boa opção realmente, vou tentar.

Comment: Acho que com HashMaps também da.

Comment: Conseguiu carregar alguma estrutura de dados com as informações do firebase? Pq aí te passo o esquema do adapter

Comment: Então, achei um jeito com o adapter mesmo, mas se quiser me mandar para comparação.

Comment: Consegui fazer usando Firebase Recyclerview e um Adapter. Agora preciso fazer uma pesquisa no RecyclerView.

Comment: Poderia postar o código? Basicamente seria filtrar os dados da estrutura de dados utilizada, setar esses dados ao adapter e depois adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), mas depende da forma que está implementado

Comment: usei como referência, então ficou bem parecido. :https://github.com/mmazzarolo/firebase-recyclerview/tree/eb8621eeab838e9f6b82bfaa50dcb057e1831821

Comment: mas vou precisar arrumar um outro jeito, tem alguma dica para criar o Adapter?